# Programming for Interface unnecessary for non-public-static member variables and local variables?

Tags: java

There are several **partly related** posts on Stackoverflow, I tried to ask the following question by leaving comment there, but I have no privilege to comment. So come this post.

Is programming for interface, e.g. `"List aList = new ArrayList();"` **unnecessary *inside private methods or for private member variables?***
For collection objects used inside private methods, `"ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();"` is perfectly fine, isn't it?
Is that thinking also correct for private member variables?
**In summary, do all *non-public-static member variables and local variables* not need to be declared for interface?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your line of thought is not incorrect, but ideally you'll want always to program to an interface than to an implementation because, in general, it will be easier to follow the practice in the long run. It will also make your code appear to be more standarized.

There are some cases, however, where you might want to use the implementation instead of the interface - for example, if you are working with a LinkedList and want to avoid some casting.

Will the world fall apart if you use `ArrayList<Something> list = new ArrayList<>()`? Of course not, but the "good" practice tells to use the interface (`List`, in this case) whenever possible.

Comment: I'm amazed you were able to grok what was being asked.

Answer (score 3):

Your question amounts to, "Should I follow best practices in cases where they don't make a difference?" And really only you (or your company's style guide) can answer that.

Personally, I always follow (what I consider to be) best practices except when there's a specific (unusual) reason not to. That way the unusual cases stick out, and I know to look closely for what might be going on. With your example, the use of `ArrayList` calls out that this object needs to be mutable, which to me is significant because it means I can't just think of it as a list of objects, but rather must think of it as its own object that happens to contain references.

The practices you follow — good or bad — will quickly become second nature to you. If you're reasonably consistent about them, you won't even have to think about them — they'll just flow from your fingertips. Don't you want them to be good ones?